# How can I get out of questions Ban twice?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have managed to get out of question Ban for the first time by answering multiple questions until I reach 100 reputation, but then I asked a new question which get some down votes and I get in question Ban again?(I have deleted the question and still banned), my questions are:

1- Can I get out of question Ban again?

2- How many reputation I have to reach to get out ( I have got 250+ ) ?

Comment: Did you get a message of any sort? If so what did it say? Did it only say you were *limited* to one question per day, or did it say you were *banned*?

Comment: Deleting questions only makes things worse...

Comment: There is no 'reputation level'; the question ban algorithm is not public, but we know that question *quality* is the most important metric in it. Offsetting a lack of question quality with answers can help, but if you then return to asking low-quality questions you can fall right back into the ban. None of us here can tell you how much rep you need to earn, because that's not the metric used.

Comment: Look, there is a reason for having a question ban. If you ask poor-quality questions, some of them not even about programming, you are meant to get a question ban, because you're creating a problem. Try to familiarize yourself with the rules instead of writing answers just for the sake of being able to ask poor questions again, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest learning how to ask better questions. After all, the entire point of the question ban is to prevent users from flooding the site with bad questions, especially when they demonstrate no signs of improvement.

You can start by studying the other questions that you're answering. Don't just answer questions for the sake of getting yourself out of the ban without learning anything from the questions that you answer, otherwise you're just going to fall back into the same hole that you climbed out of, rendering all your efforts moot and reinforcing the point of the question ban.

I highly doubt your absolute reputation score has much of an influence on the question ban, if at all. Focusing solely or primarily on increasing your reputation will eventually be an exercise in futility.